# Convert date string to MM DD in react - not vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I understand how to do this outside of react. I have a date string that is returned from API in an object. I need to reformat it so instead of "2022-12-13T06:00Z" it would read "December 13". The object holds utcStart as "2022-12-13T06:00Z". Currently the below displays as "2022-12-13T06:00Z"

```
const eventDates = useRecoilValue(eventDatesState);
return (
    <Grid item xs={12}>
        eventDates.map (data =>(
            <ListItem>
                <span className="date">{eventDates.utcStart}</span>
            </ListItem>
        ))
    </Grid>
)
```

Since it is in a map function, I don't know how to do this for each one.This doesn't work

```
<span className="date">{new Date(calendarContent.utcStart)}</span>
```

Comment: @pilchard - no, if it was just in vanilla JS I'd be done. But I get several "react-dom.development.js:14887 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Date]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." errors using react

Comment: Then you aren't putting out a string, so possibly read through the duplicate. `toLocaleDateString()` outputs a string while your example is just trying to render a complete Date object.

Comment: I think you're just forgetting the brackets.

instead of 

```jsx
eventDates.map (data =>(
...
))
```

You could do

```jsx
eventDates.map(data => {
   [JS logic where you convert the date and create a variable for each item here]
   return (
      [JSX components with the variable declared above here]
   )
}
```

Comment: it's all just vanilla JS so long as you embed it correctly in the JSX

Comment: It probably is formatting Im having issue with, but just doesn't work for me inside the map.

Comment: Have you tried the curly brackets? You can do Vanilla JS before returning a JSX (React) component.

You can use the code to convert the data after the curly bracket and declare a variable to store the result. Then you can do `return ()`  with the JSX inside the parenthesis. On the JSX you can instantiate the variable with the date.

I'll create an answer to exemplify what I'm saying here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
var date = new Date('2022-12-13T06:00Z');

// Use the options object to specify the desired format
var options = { month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
var formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);

console.log(formattedDate);
// OUTPUT
// December 13
```

**Here's how to do this in React**

```
export default function MyComponent() {
  var date = new Date('2022-12-13T06:00Z');

  // Use the options object to specify the desired format
  var options = { month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
  var formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);

  return (
    <span>{formattedDate }</span>
  )

}
```

Comment: I updated my answer on how to use it in React. It should work, but I don't have all the details about how it doesn't it work for you

Comment: maybe accept `date` as a prop instead of as a static variable in the component, might be clearer for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Example using the answer above:

```
export default function GridWithFormattedDates() {
    const eventDates = useRecoilValue(eventDatesState);
    return (
        <Grid item xs={12}>
            {eventDates.map(eventDate => {
                const date = new Date(eventDate.utcStart);

                const options = { month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
                const formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
                return (
                    <ListItem>
                        <span className="date">{formattedDate}</span>
                    </ListItem>
                );
            })}
        </Grid>
    );
}
```